# Fundamental theorem of algebra - connecting equivalent formulations

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How can these two statements of the fundamental theorem of algebra be reconciled into equivalent formulations of the same concept:

> 1. The field of complex numbers is algebraically closed.
> 2. Every non-zero, single-variable, degree n polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly n complex roots.

Comment: Your 1. is equivalent to every non-zero polynomial has at least one complex root, now use division and induction to get 2.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you. I'm curious about these concepts, and it's not an exercise or test. Do you have any more or less accessible reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field

Comment: Many HS-level algebra/precalculus textbooks _prove_ The Complete Factorization Theorem, assuming The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, by repeatedly applying The Factor Theorem. For example, the text "Algebra and Trigonometry, 3rd Ed (2011)", by the Stewart/Redlin/Watson is one such text.

Answer (score 0):

> Fundamental theorem of algebra:
>   *The field of complex numbers is algebraically closed*  =   *Every non-zero polynomial has at least one complex root.*

The number of complex (including real) roots equals the degree of the polynomial. Hence it can be factored into as many linear factors as the degree of the polynomial...

> Complete factorization theorem:

A polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ with complex coefficients and complex roots $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n$ can be factored into

$$P(x)=c\cdot (x-r_1)\cdot(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$$

with $c$ corresponding to a (non-zero) complex number.

> [Factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem):

The factor theorem states that a polynomial has a factor $x - r_1$ if and only if $P(r_1)=0$ (i.e. $r_1$ is a root).

Hence, $P(x)$ can be factored as

$$P(x)=(x-r_1)\cdot Q_1(x)$$

The quotient group $Q_1(x)$ is of degree $n-1.$

> "by repeatedly applying The Factor Theorem..."

If $r_2$ is a factor of $Q_1(x),$ then $P(x)$ can be factored into

$$P(x)=(x-r_1)\cdot(x-r_2)\cdot Q_2(x)$$

reducing by one the degree of the quotient polynomial. And this process can be repeated until we arrive at a constant term, $c:$

$$P(x)=c\cdot (x-r_1)\cdot(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n).$$

This proves the second formulation of the FTA in the OP:

> *Every non-zero, single-variable, degree n polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly n complex roots.*

Comment: Thank you for the comments (partially quoted). I think this is it. If there is a good post online that I can link to the "complete factorization theorem" please edit the post, or send it as a comment.